# How to skip disc cache with Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

How can I ommit disc caching in per request basis as in Glide with setDiscCacheStrategy (other than downloadimg the image normally and than evic it from disc cachd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use [`ImageRequestBuilder`](http://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/request/ImageRequestBuilder.html) to build [`ImageRequest`](http://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/request/ImageRequest.html) objects, you need to call [`disableDiskCache()`](http://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/request/ImageRequestBuilder.html#disableDiskCache()) on the builder.

For example:

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
    .newBuilderWithSource(uri)
    .disableDiskCache()
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

if its just for debug builds you can do it another way. in my case i was not using imageRequestBuilder.  so i just added a random number as a query param to the url fresco is loading.  it will make fresco get a new image everytime almost. no cache.